# How do I extend the end of a clip in iMovie?

Tags: imovie

Need help with an iMovie I am putting together for a memorial this weekend.  I've finished the movie, but was hoping to extend the first clip.  Since I am using a 'ken burns' crop for the clip, the view pans from the bottom of the photo to the top in the clip.  Once the view reaches the top of the photo, I'd like it to hold for about four seconds.  I can't seem to make that happen, even if I'm using the inspector.  Any step by step tips folks can offer up would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!
Leah

Answer (score 2):

1. Click the clip after the clip that you wish to pause
2. Press ⇧← to go back to the end of the clip that you wish
3. Press ⌥F to add a freeze-frame
4. Delete the third clip
5. Set the second clip to Fit or Crop to Fill